# Imbalanced dataset, finding the statistical significance of a Matthews Correlation Coefficient (MCC) in binary classification (what is a good MCC)?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, cross-validation, correlation, model-evaluations

I have a very imbalanced dataset. Thus, I am using MCC to evaluate the performance of various ML algorithms. It appears that literature is entirely lacking in ways to evaluate how good an MCC score is. I understand MCC is the same as the Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient (PPMCC) and problem dependent, but my question is: Can we evaluate the statistical significance of it using Pearon's correlation coefficient's relationship to Chi square?

PPMCC= |MCC| = Sqrt[(Chi^2)/n]

In other words, can we conclude from the relation above that By having: imbalanced Binary Classification Problem, N = 1000, and χ² >= 3.85 (p < 0.05, df = 1 received from critical value table)

The following MCC would significant (p<.05) (i.e. we reject the null hypothesis that the correlation is 0):

MCC >= sqrt ( 3.85 / 1000 ) which is MCC >= 0.06

So in other words, we can reject the null hypothesis that the correlation is 0 if MCC is over .06 and accept the alternative hypothesis that we do indeed have a correlation (that is, our classifier is performing better than chance)?

This question is basically the same as the one asked here many years prior that had no sufficient answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94563/measuring-statistical-significance-of-binary-classification-using-matthews-corre which had a lot of upvotes but no good answers (the only answer was flawed in my eyes since it starting mentioning ROC curves and didn't seem to answer the question). I think this is an important question without an answer. (the only answer was flawed in my eyes since it starting mentioning ROC curves and didn't seem to answer the question). I think this is an important question without a definitive answer.